# Get all names from array and pluck them together Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I got an array in witch are nested arrays and I want to get names from those nested arrays and display them together. I have been searching a lot and can't figure out how. I am using laravel 8.

```
array:2 [▼
  "5dd48809b061f7a3828cb5267794ce39" => array:10 [▼
    "name" => "test"
  ]
  "7d504e7f837b2f9bb03dca5f9c8da9f5" => array:10 [▼
    "name" => "test2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Something like `collect($array)->map->pluck('name')` ? If not can you be more specific on what you need?

Comment: yea so I have data stored in database as json then I take it do json_decode and get the array then I want to display names as I mentioned in the post this is how my code looks like now.
        $orders =  Order::get()->first();
        $order = $orders->cart;
        json_decode($order, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in basic PHP with the `array_column` function.

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');
```

The above example would output:

```
array(
 [0] => 'test',
 [1] => 'test2',
);
```

You can also keep the ID as key, **if it exists within the nested array**:

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name', 'id');
```

The above example would e.g. output:

```
array(
 [1515] => 'test',
 [2522] => 'test2',
);
```

There are more examples in the documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: it works just fine to get names but I need that to display on blade I tried every way but it just doesnt

Comment: to display an array in blade views you would have to loop through them with a foreach or select the key from the array explicit: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: remember to pass the $names array as view data